# Moving from one fragment to another in a custom listview in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview

I have created a navigation drawer for my app from [androidhive.info](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/). In that navigation drawer, in one fragment, I have created a custom listview which shows the elements with a name and image. Now upon clicking an item of the custom listview, I need to show the details of the clicked list element. For that I have created another fragment. Now upon clicking the listview element, I should move onto the details of the selected element. The code which I have used for moving from one fragment to another is this:

```
Fragment fragment=new ImportantNumbersFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But the `getSupportFragmentManager()` is showing an error in eclipse like this: `The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type PagesFragment`. This is the code of my custom listview fragment.

**PagesFragment.class**

```
public class PagesFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener{

    Typeface tf;
    ListView lv;
    List<SimpleRow>rowItems;
    public PagesFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);
    Helper help=new Helper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    String choice1="സര്‍ക്കാര്‍ സ്ഥാപനങ്ങള്‍";
    String choice1new=help.changemalayalam(new Data(choice1));
    String choice2="പത്രം";
    String choice2new=help.changemalayalam(new Data(choice2));
    String choice3="ന്യൂസ് ചാനല്‍";
    String choice3new=help.changemalayalam(new Data(choice3));
    String choice4="യൂണിവേഴ്സിറ്റികള്‍";
    String choice4new=help.changemalayalam(new Data(choice4));
    String choice5="പഞ്ചായത്ത് ഓഫീസ്";
    String choice5new=help.changemalayalam(new Data(choice5));
    String choice6="ഇന്‍ഷുറന്‍സ്";
    String choice6new=help.changemalayalam(new Data(choice6));
    String choice7="പോലീസ് സ്റ്റേഷന്‍";
    String choice7new=help.changemalayalam(new Data(choice7));
    String choice8="ഫയര്‍ സ്റ്റേഷന്‍";
    String choice8new=help.changemalayalam(new Data(choice8));
    ArrayList<String>choice=new ArrayList<String>();
    choice.add(choice1new);
    choice.add(choice2new);
    choice.add(choice3new);
    choice.add(choice4new);
    choice.add(choice5new);
    choice.add(choice6new);
    choice.add(choice7new);
    choice.add(choice8new);

    lv=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list1);
    rowItems=new ArrayList<SimpleRow>();

     for (int i = 0; i < choice.size(); i++) {
        SimpleRow item = new SimpleRow(choice.get(i));
        rowItems.add(item);
        CustomSimpleListAdapter adapter = new CustomSimpleListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_single, rowItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on position "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//Here upon clicking the list element, I need to go to ImportantNubersFragment

    Fragment fragment=new ImportantNumbersFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on position "+arg2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**ImportantNumbersFragment.class**

```
public class ImportantNumbersFragment extends Fragment {

    public ImportantNumbersFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**fragment_important_numbers.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<FrameLayout android:name="fragments.YourInitialFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

I want to move from PagesFragment to ImportantNumbersFragment upon clicking the list element in the custom listview. So in the OnListItemClick, I have given the code for moving from fragment to another. I have to do this in the sameway as that of moving from one activity to another activity using intents like: 
`Intent i=new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
startActivity(i);`.

Since I'm new to fragments, I don't know how this can be achieved in fragments. That's why I have asked here. Can someone please point out the errors in this code. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Are you using `Support package` for `fragment` in all extended Fragment
  Classes, Check !
  .
- I myself have used the code from `AndroidHive` and it works perfectly
  .
- There it does not uses `Support package` for extended fragment classes
  .
- Somewhere in code you are using a Support import, Make sure you
  maintain uniformity among imports
  .
- `Programatically Speaking for ex`::
  **If you are using support package use codes like these**

---

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
```

---

- **If you are not using support package use codes imports** ::

---

```
import android.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.DrawerLayout;
```

---

### {EDIT - Sample on how one of the way to perform fragment transaction}

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Fragment fragment;
    String className;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Store the name of the class
        className=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        //First fragment should be mounted on oncreate of main activity
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {  
            /*fragment=FragmentOne.newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(className).commit();
            */

            Fragment newFragment = FragmentOne.newInstance();  
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
            ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();  
            Log.d("FRAGMENT-A", "fragment added to backstack");
        }

    }
}
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.sample.screennavigation.UtilRangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener;

    public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

        //Declare variables that hold the data for configuration change

        public static FragmentOne newInstance(){
            Log.d("FragmentOne", "newInstance");
            FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
            return  fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("FragmentOne", "onCreateView");
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

            return view;
        }

    }
```

### {EDIT-2}

---

- `PagesFragment` ... ***is using a support package somewhere, check
  it*** !
- Check imports of `pagefragment`

---

```
But the getSupportFragmentManager() is showing an error in eclipse like this: The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type PagesFragment.
```

- Error in your code clearly says you are using a supportpackage import
  and it is conflicting the execution
- Rememmber you cannot mix the imports

***Hope it helps !, let me know if you need any additional info***

Comment: can you please explain to me how to create a new fragment and its layout and also move from my current fragment to new fragment on list item click event..What all codes has to be used for moving from one fragment to another...

Comment: @TeeJay .... See the edit on my answer (I use support package)..... This is how i use fragment transaction ..... what you are doing is also correct ..... you just need to check your imports and maintain uniformity

Comment: @ Tee Jay .... If my answer helped .... mark it as accepted ! .... check the green arrow at the top !

Comment: Actually what you said may be correct. But that was not the solution to my problem. Actually I got the solution by myself. That's why didn't mark your answer as accepted answer. Any way you give me some info about that. Thanks...